# Create datetime from columns in a DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I got a DataFrame with these columns :

```
year month  day gender  births
```

I'd like to create a new column type "Date" based on the column year, month and day as : "yyyy-mm-dd"

I'm just beginning in Python and I just can't figure out how to proceed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using pandas to create your dataframe, you can try:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2015,2016],'month':[2,3],'day':[4,5],'gender':['m','f'],'births':[0,2]})

>>> df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:,0:3])

>>> df
   year  month  day gender  births      dates
0  2015      2    4      m       0 2015-02-04
1  2016      3    5      f       2 2016-03-05
```

Taken from the example [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and the slicing (iloc use) "Selection" section of "10 minutes to pandas" [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#selection).

Comment: Yes it works even better. I just had to add : 
data['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(data.iloc[:,0:3], errors = 'coerce') 
cause apparently I had some out values range

Answer (score 0):

You can use .assign
For example:

```
df2= df.assign(ColumnDate = df.Column1.astype(str) + '- ' + df.Column2.astype(str) + '-' df.Column3.astype(str) )
```

It is simple and it is much faster than lambda if you have tonnes of data.

Comment: I would check the type of the column that is created, does this create a character column or a datetime column? You can run df2.dtypes to check. If pandas doesn't convert to a date, the behavior of the column might not be as expected.

Comment: You're right mgrollins, it creates a character column